# How to parse all expressions inside double quotes from a String easily?

Tags: java, string, split

I have a String, something like `["first" "second" "third"]`.

Is there an easy way to get all the expressions within quotes as a String array?

I know I can parse it char by char, but maybe there is a simpler way to do it?

Surprisingly, google doesn't give me any solutions.

Comment: Please refer http://javacjava.com/StringSplit.html

Comment: but this will give me unneeded elements like {"[","first"," ".... etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it:

```
String[] terms = str.replaceAll("^.*?\"|\"[^\"]*$", "").split("\"\\s+\"");
```

This works by first removing the first and last quotes and all characters between them and the ends (via the call to `replaceAll()`, then splitting on quote-whitespace-quote, leaving you with just the content you're after.

---

Some test code:

```
String str = "[\"first\" \"second\" \"third\"] ";
String[] terms = str.replaceAll("^.*?\"|\"[^\"]*$", "").split("\"\\s+\"");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(terms));
```

Output:

```
[first, second, third]
```

Comment: Thanx ! can you give a little explanation on split() part?